# How web api differentiates the parameters type in overload scenario?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, overloading

Suppose I am having POST method for Student and User. Since as limit to object definition is both having properties with same names. like

```
Student : First Name ,Last Name,Address.
Employee: First Name ,Last Name,Address.
```

and say my POST method is like as :

```
 public void Post([FromBody]Student _student)
        {//my code
        }
```

and another is same in same class:

```
 public void Post([FromBody]Employee _employee)
        {//my code
        }
```

When accessing this method from external device say from Android, It will be the JSon object. formatted with same parameter and values. how rout will identify which method to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a separate route  for each method like the following code:

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController
```

{

```
    [Route("api/Contacts/Students")]
    public void Post([FromBody] Student student)
    {

    }

    [Route("api/Contacts/Employees")]
    public void Post([FromBody] Employee employee)
    {

    }
```

}

Otherwise, Web API will throw an exception owing to ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks... but again how rout will map the specific method ? From mobile device there will be same request for both these methods. So do I need to provide any specific URL to access these methods (same like you added in attribute)?

Comment: That's right. You will have to provide https://www.yourdomain.com/api/contacts/students and https://www.yourdomain.com/api/contacts/employees. Otherwise, the methods won't be reached. One way to test the methods is using a browser or fiddler, and then debug them.